# Programmatically trigger the stop button from a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to implement a hard limit on a how long a web page can load via a Chrome extension. I have seen a number of implementations that suggest using a content script to call `window.stop()`, but in some cases the browser is never going to execute that JavaScript because it's still attempting to load a page that is going to time out. An example of such a site is http://blackhole.webpagetest.org.

At a very basic level, I need the extension to be able to hit the "Stop" button in the browser after a specified amount of time.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in Chrome?

Comment: Perhaps, instead of Content Scripts, you could addListener in a Background Script using Chrome webRequest to listen for onBeforeRequest and onCompleted. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Comment: @JayA.Little I am currently trying to use WebExtensions already and have looked at the `webRequest` API but it doesn't seem that you can cancel a request which is already in-flight.